# What is the meaning of "I said when we knew"?

Tags: meaning

In Angelina Jolie directed movie "By The Sea (2015)", Roland take his wife Vanessa to church. 
Vanessa came out of church and said this words to
her husband.

> Vanessa: I prayed that God might forgive me for all the horrible
>   things **I said when we knew**. And I prayed for the strength to mean it.
>   Because I don't. I'm angry.
>
> Roland: I'm angry, too, baby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Movie Script soon after Vanessa and Roland strike up a friendship with an attractive young couple staying in the room next to them they discover that the wall between their two rooms has a disused radiator pipe hole, enabling them to watch the couple in their bedroom talking and having sex. Vanessa wakes Roland up in the morning asking whether he wants to have sex with the women in the next room:

> -
>   Wake up. Wake up.
>   - Wake up!
>   - What?
>   - What?
>   - Do you wanna fuck her?
>   - Huh?
>   - The woman next door, do you want to fuck her?
>   - Honey, what are you doing?
>   - Don't pretend you don't know what I'm talking about.
>   - I don't know what the fuck you're talking about. Get off! ([By The Sea - movie script)](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=by-the-sea)

They argue and fight and she keeps on saying terrible things to Roland.

> Gradually their experiences at the hotel enable Vanessa and Roland to start patching up their relationship. However, Vanessa attempts a liaison with the young husband in the next room, interrupted violently by Roland, who has been watching through the wall. He bruises the husband, who must later explain to his wife and does so truthfully, seriously damaging the relationship between the young couple. This also triggers a confrontation between Vanessa and Roland, during which he tells her that if she wishes to hurt him, she should just go ahead and hurt him physically. Roland asserts that her seduction of the husband was motivated by his wife's envy of the young couple - particularly of their ability to bear children. Roland physically restrains Vanessa against a wall and makes her speak of herself being barren which they haven't been able to talk about. After a short struggle, Vanessa breaks down and weeps for her loss. Later, Roland explains to the young wife that two miscarriages caused Vanessa's lasting grief, withdrawal and behavior toward her husband. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By_the_Sea_(2015_film)))

Later in the church she is referring to that moment.

Comment: This is a nice summary of the movie, but it doesn't seem to have a lot to do with English.

Answer (score 1):

"Knew" here can only be understood from context, because what she knows is implicit.

So "when we knew" could be understood as:

- when we knew [what we know now]
- when we knew [the situation]
- after we found out [what had happened]
- once we became aware [of the situation]

So "all the horrible things I said when we knew" can be understood as "all the horrible things [that] I said when we knew [about something]".

Answer (score -1):

look dear , there's a misunderstanding .
You should not have asked for **I said when i knew**.

You should have asked : **When i know**

for all the horrible things I said, when we knew

In this sentence , The word **When** is like **IF** and refers back to intentionally terrible things that were said.

which means : I've asked forgiveness for all the terrible things I said 
(In spite of knowing that they were terrible things to say , i said them ).